# scrapy: 'exceptions.KeyError' in CrawlSpider

Tags: python, regex, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to scrape all relevant fields on the following website, so that I can load all the data into a spreadsheet:

```
http://yellowpages.com.gh/Home.aspx?
```

I am guessing that a CrawlSpider is what I want, so this is what I have been trying to build:

---

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.item import Item
class YellowGH2Spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "yellowGH2"
    allowed_domains = ["yellowpages.com.gh"]
    start_urls = ["http://yellowpages.com.gh/Home.aspx"]
    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'http://yellowpages.com.gh/Home.aspx?mcaid=\d+#tabs-2', ))),
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'http://yellowpages.com.gh/(Home|Search-Results).aspx?mcaid=[0-9&eca1id=]+(&lcaid=)?\d+#tabs-2', )), callback='parse_item'),
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'http://yellowpages.com.gh/Company-Details/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.aspx?returnurl=/Search-Results.aspx', )), callback='parse_item'),
        )
    def parse(self, response):
        #hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        #filename = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        #open(filename, 'wb').write(response.body)

        sel = Selector(response)
        item = Item()
        #item['catName']=sel.xpath('//div[@class="oneDirCat"]/h3/a/text()').extract()
        item['catLink']=sel.xpath('//div[@class="oneDirCat"]/h3/a/@href').extract()
        item['subcatText']=sel.xpath('//ul/li/a/@href').extract()
        item['subcatLink']=sel.xpath('//div[@class="oneDirCat"]/h3/a/text()').extract()
        item['company']=sel.xpath('//label/text()').extract()
        item['more']=sel.xpath('//td[@valign="bottom"]/a/@href').extract()
        item['address']=sel.xpath('//td[2]/text()').extract()
        item['postAddress']=sel.xpath('//td[4]/text()').extract()
        item['city']=sel.xpath('//td[6]/text()').extract()
        item['region']=sel.xpath('//td[8]/text()').extract()
        item['mobile']=sel.xpath('//td[12]/text()').extract()
        item['emailtext']=sel.xpath('//td[16]/a/text()').extract()
        item['emailLink']=sel.xpath('//td[16]/a/@href').extract()
        item['webtext']=sel.xpath('//td[18]/a/text()').extract()
        item['webLink']=sel.xpath('//td[18]/a/@href').extract()
        return item


            #print catName, catLink, subcatText, subcatLink, company, more,
            #address, postAddress, city, region, mobile, emailtext, emailLink,
            #webtext, webLink
```

---

However, on running this on the Command Prompt, I am getting the following error:

***exceptions.KeyError: 'Item does not support field: catLink'***

What is/are the most likely reason/s for an error such as this one occurring? Could it be connected with the format of my XPaths? Or could it be connected with the fact that this spider shares the same items.py file as the original spider in the project?

My items.py code is as follows:

```
# Define here the models for your scraped items
#
# See documentation in:
# http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html

from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class YellowghItem(Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = Field()
      catName = Field()
      catLink = Field()
      subcatText = Field()
      subcatLink = Field()
      company = Field()
      more = Field()
      address = Field()
      postAddress = Field()
      city = Field()
      region = Field()
      mobile = Field()
      emailtext = Field()
      emailLink = Field()
      webtext = Field()
      webLink = Field()

      #pass
```

Comment: Show us your `item` class definition

Answer (score 4):

So here is why you are seeing the error. Your `item.py` file has defined the class `YellowghItem`. This class has the class member `catLink`.

But in your spider, you are not instantiating this class. Instead you are instantiating an `Item()` class. I bet there is another class called `Item` in your project which has no `catLink` defined as it's member.

Do these changes in your spider:

- Change the import from `scrapy.item import YellowghItem`
- In your `parse` method, instantiate an object of this class with:

  ```
  item = YellowghItem()
  ```

Try with these changes and I think you will be able to resolve this error.

Hope this helps.